# SlidingMenu with ViewPager conflict

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, slidingmenu

I'm trying to get [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) to work alongside `ViewPager` and I have followed the examples inside the library to the letter. The source for my Activity can be found bellow.

The problem is that despite the fact that the `SlidingMenu` and `ViewPager` work fine together there is this problem that after opening the `SlidingMenu` for the first time and closing it afterwards the `ViewPager` starts acting weird.

By weird I mean when you swipe to right and left the UI gets stuck on one page and doesn't change and I mean it's only the UI as I can see in the logger that the pages actually change.

I have searched the web extensively and although there has been a lot of similar problems with implementing `SlidingMenu` alongside `ViewPager`, my problem seems to be unique.

Any help is appreciated.

```
public class MainTabActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainTabActivity";

    @InjectView(R.id.tabHostPager)
    ViewPager tabHostPager;
    @InjectView(R.id.tabs)
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabStrip;

    FragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tab);
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.sliding_menu_layout);
        loadSlidingMenu();
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        pagerAdapter = new MainTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        tabHostPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        //Assign the TabStrip it's ViewPager
        tabStrip.setViewPager(tabHostPager);

        tabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
                        break;
                    default:
                        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
        tabHostPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }

    private void loadSlidingMenu() {
        // configure the SlidingMenu
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        getSlidingMenu().setShadowWidth(100);
        getSlidingMenu().setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        getSlidingMenu().setBehindWidth(width / 100 * 90);
    }

    private class MainTabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MainTabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return Friends.newInstance();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Home";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: if you are not using the menu like in facebook, more like youtube menu then you can go for toolbar, with drawer which is supported in appcompat.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Thanks, but I don't need a `Navigation Drawer` and unlike Facebook I need my `SlidingMenu` to open with a swipe from the first page not with a button on the `ActionBar`.

Comment: try using the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Again no luck friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve it. It had something to with `manageLayers` method from the `SlidingMenu` class.
Commenting out the method body was all it took:

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void manageLayers(float percentOpen) {
        /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) return;

        boolean layer = percentOpen > 0.0f && percentOpen < 1.0f;
        final int layerType = layer ? View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE : View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE;

        if (layerType != getContent().getLayerType()) {
            getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.v(TAG, "changing layerType. hardware? " + (layerType == View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE));
                    getContent().setLayerType(layerType, null);
                    getMenu().setLayerType(layerType, null);
                    if (getSecondaryMenu() != null) {
                        getSecondaryMenu().setLayerType(layerType, null);
                    }
                }
            });
        }*/
    }
```